2.5A 250V power cord for a laptop
My girlfriend’s sister is moving to the United States from Brazil.  She has a laptop with a 2.5 A 250v type N laptop charger. What converter/adapter would be needed to make this work? It seems like 250V is a lot for a laptop.

The input line shows: 100-240V , 1.8 A , 50-60 Hz

It is a sure bet that her laptop doesn't need 250V, 25A.  25 A is like a main circuit in a house.  You'd be looking at like 6000 watts of power.  A better way to ask this question would be to post a picture of the power supply brick and the power cable and ask if (and how) it can be used in the US.

Laptops typically don't use AC at all.

25A at 250V would be more than 8 horsepowers.  A device drawing that kind of wattage is not something you want on your lap.

I edited the title to be consistent with the body text.

What does the input voltage range on the charger say?  I can't read that on the photo.

It it 100-240V , 1.8 A , 50-60 Hz?

That’s correct, appreciate everyone’s help so far.

It's a laptop adaptor.  Read the specifications on the back -- it says that the input power requirement is 100-240V, 1.8A.
When she hits the US, she just needs to get a power cord that'll fit the local sockets and her laptop adaptor -- there's a lot of computer stores that'll be able to set her up.

This charger can handle both Brazilian 220V/60Hz and US 110V/60Hz. As well as European 230V/50Hz.


110V and 127V, both 60Hz, are also used in Brazil (the second one being the most common).
